# Website layout getting messed up with zooming

Tags: html, css

I am getting problems with the website I'm working on while zooming in and out. The layout is getting messed while zooming.

The items in the header won't stay centered, but moving to the left while zooming out, or moving to the right while zooming in.

Also, I have a image background (in CSS) and it won't stay centered when zooming in. Could I get some help with this problem. Thanks

Here is the HTML and CSS code:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header-wrapper {
  background: #ebebeb;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}
#header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
#logo {
  width: 128px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("pictures/logo2.png");
  margin-left: 250px;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  top: 28px;
}
#nav-wrapper {
  width: 650px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 340px;
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
}
#nav {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
#nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 810px;
  background-image: url("pictures/banner3-2.png");
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
}
#about {
  width: 100%;
  height: 820px;
  background: #ebebeb;
  position: relative;
  top: 860px;
}
#lorem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 820px;
  background: #46717f;
  position: relative;
  top: 860px;
}
#contact {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 860px;
}
#header-wrapper a {
  color: black;
}
#header-wrapper a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#header-wrapper a:hover {
  color: #46717f;
}
#header-wrapper a:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://openfontlibrary.org/face/8bit-wonder" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div id="wrapper">

  <h1 id="homee"></h1>
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="logo"></div>

      <div id="nav-wrapper">
        <div id="nav">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#homee" title="Return to the Homepage">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#aboutt" title="Return to the Homepage">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#loremm" title="Return to the Homepage">LOREM</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contactt" title="Return to the Homepage">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="home">
  </div>


  <div id="about">
  </div>
  <h1 id="aboutt"></h1>

  <div id="lorem">
  </div>
  <h1 id="loremm"></h1>

  <div id="contact"></div>
  <h1 id="contactt"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I converted your code into a snippet so that the users can see a live preview and removed the local links since they are unneccessary. Please correct me if something went wrong.

Comment: It still doens't work. I've tried so many ways, but still no results.